# How to get pdf file data from whatsapp to my app in android?

Tags: java, android

In my application, I want to open a pdf file from the WhatsApp application to my app. I need to send that pdf file data to server I can't able get the proper path. Please give me any suggestions to get the file path along with the base64 encoded data. Thanks in advance.

I can able to show the pdf in my application through URI.

In my manifest file

```
<activity android:name= ".activities.MyActivity"
                          ........>

    <intent-filter tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType= "application/pdf" />
        <data android:host="*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

when I am trying to get the exact file path from URI it is coming like "content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/4" from this file how can I get the `base64data`?

Comment: "from this file how can i will get the base64data?" -- it is not a file. It is a `Uri`. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by that `Uri`.

Comment: I tried that also but i didn't get the InputStream from the Uri. Anyway thanks for your response CommonsWare

Comment: this is working for me  thank you all..                                                                           
 InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);

Answer (score 0):

**Works fine for me**

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
 byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
 String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
```